# How to trim very long line in bash output?

Tags: bash, command-line

When I use `ps aux`, some of the rows from the output are very long (thousands of characters) because its `COMMAND` has too many args. This makes the output unreadable because it those very long lines wrap around in my terminal.

How can I easily trim the output to, say, maximum of 256 characters for any bash command output?

Comment: `ps aux | less -S`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `cut`, e.g.

```
ps aux | cut -c1-256
```